# listview scrolls to bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have an activity with the following layout.

[image]

So in this screen, initally the `ListView`is empty. I type some text in `EditText`and click on the search icon next to it, the app fetched the items from server and populates the `ListView`. Now the problem is that the `ListView` scrolls down to the last item.

Code in my `onClick()` of search `Button`

```
                    String str_searchTxt = mEt_search.getText().toString().trim();
            if (str_searchTxt.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.ENTER_MANDATORY),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            // get items List in araryList
            itemList = getItemList(messageHandler,str_searchTxt);
```

Code in my message handler:

```
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 2:
            String txt = msg.getData().getString("text");

            Log.i("Result", txt);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (txt.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                lview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                adapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(
                        SearchAssetActivity.this, itemList);
                lview3.setAdapter(adapter);
                lview3.setOnItemClickListener(SearchAssetActivity.this);
                lview3.requestFocus();
                lview3.setSelection(0);             

            }
        }
```

Comment: you question is not clear refresh it

Comment: post your code of onClick of search button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**setSelection(position)**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29) of ListView,

```
mListView.setSelection(first_position);
```

Else you can try,

```
mListView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.I have edited my post to add code. as you see in my `onclick()` I do set the selection. I'm doing this in the `onItemClick()` also.

Comment: My problem is not setting th selection.If you read the post title, it says **ListView scrolls to last item**. setSelection(position) just highlights the first element.But the list is scrolled to last item..I need to scroll up the list till top to see that the first item is selected.

Comment: Try to call `list_view.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();`

Comment: still doesn't work :( I did notice one thing . For the first time the list scrolls down anyways. But once I select an item, and then if I perform search any no. of times the ListView doesn't scroll and shows the first item selected. I believe this issue is more with ListView not gaining focus after every search. We just `setSelection(0);` which is not same as focus.

Comment: Well you can come [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1531/casual-chat) so that we can discuss further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yourscrollview.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! However, I don't have a scrollview.The screen is like a Listview in center and fixed searchBar at Top and Two button at bottom. Only the Listview scrolls non of the other elements scroll.

Comment: Everytime I fetch a new set of results I repopulate the list using following code `lview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         adapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(
           SearchAssetActivity.this, itemList);
         lview3.setAdapter(adapter);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         lview3.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();` Still when once after I populate the list refreshes and scroll to last item of the list.

Comment: @Lalit: After everything said and done. It works on Icream Sandwich but the problem still remains on Ginger bread which is not satisfying :(